# Navigate from a view to another

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

The main: xxxVieController
and the second: OptionViewController

in xxxView controller I have

```
.h
@interface iMetroAlertViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIButton *option;
}

-(IBAction) goToOption;
```

and

```
.m
@implementation iMetroAlertViewController

-(IBAction) goToOption{
    NSLog(@"Works");
    OptionViewController *dvController = [[OptionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OptionView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
    [dvController release];
    dvController = nil;
}
```

Of course a OptionViewController.xib, .m and .h are created...

When I push on the button, nothing happens (the link is done cause I have an NSLog

I don't understand why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It probably doesn't work because you don't have a navigation controller, so calling `self.navigationController` returns `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create the navigation controller

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
 {   
    RootViewController *mainMenuVC = [[RootViewController alloc] init];   
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainMenuVC];
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: No statement after a return will be executed.

Comment: Where do I write this code? What you call "RootViewController is my xxxViewController or OptionViewController? Thanks

Comment: in your xxxViewController write this... and in optionViewController write your code mentioned in your question...

Comment: refer this link for the basics of uinavigation controller http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I wrote in the iMetroAlertController (xxxViewController): 

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{   
    iMetroAlertViewController *mainMenuVC = [[iMetroAlertViewController alloc] init];   
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainMenuVC];
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

It gives un error 'navigationController' undeclared

Comment: mainMenuVC is leaking. add `[mainMenuVC release];` just before return.